# Cómo implementar autorización desde una tabla externa en laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-7

¿Cómo podría hacer para implementar un login desde otra tabla que no es la default de laravel (users)?

La nueva tabla (usuarios) no tiene modelo, ni controller. Recién la importé desde otra base de datos.

Lo que hice fué modificar el archivo auth.php así:

```
'guards' => [
    // 'web' => [
    //     'driver' => 'session',
    //     'provider' => 'users',
    // ],
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'usuarios',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
],

'providers' => [
    // 'users' => [
    //     'driver' => 'eloquent',
    //     'model' => User::class,
    // ],

    'usuarios' => [
        'driver' => 'database',
        'table' => 'usuarios',
    ],
],
```

El error que obtuve al intentar iniciar sesión fue:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'email' in
> 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `usuarios` where `email` =
> luran@gmail.com limit 1)

dado que en mi nueva tabla el campo email se llama mail simplemente.

Comment: Es un login desde cero o por medio de algún paquete?, De ser así cual usas?

Answer (score 0):

Veo que tu error es por usar un nombre de columna  distinto al que es por defecto. Para solucionar el problema deberías sobre escribir los siguientes métodos en tu LoginController.

```
protected function validateLogin(Request $request)
{
     $request->validate([
         'mail' => 'required|email',
         'password' => 'required|string',
      ]);
}

protected function credentials(Request $request)
{
    return array_merge($request->only('mail', 'password'));
}
```

Con esto le decimos que queremos validar al usuario usando la tabla `mail` en lugar de `email`.
En cualquier caso, no especificas las columnas de tu nueva tabla, por lo que mail, deberás reemplazarlo por el nombre de la columna que desees ocupar como email.